# Nested loop through in R to give DF position when criteria is met

Tags: r, loops

I am running a nested for loop with an If-clause to determine which correlation in my matrix is above 90% (.9) or less than 100% (1). When running the loop I created it only gives the below output:

[image: R issue]

Please see my code below:

```
colss = ncol(x)
rowss = nrow(x)

for (i in rowss){
 for (j in colss){
   if (x[i,j] > .9 || x[i,j] < 1){
    print(x[i,j])
  }
 }
}
```

Is there a way to get the position in the DF that has the values needed **(>.9 || < 1)?**

Example output:

> [12] .90
>
> [15] .92098

*Disclosure: I tried looking at others questions that were similar to mine but the answers didn't make total sense, so if you could please dumb it down I would appreciate it.*

Comment: try changing rowss to 1:rowss and colss to 1:colss in the for loop

Comment: That worked very well!
Would you happen to know how I could get the position in the DF? its only giving the values that meet the criteria.

example:
[1] 0.9447266
[1] 0.9447266

Comment: are you sure your criteria is (>.9 || < 1)? it would match all numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get position that match your criteria, try `which`

```
DF <- matrix(runif(20),4)
DF
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
# [1,] 0.0794861 0.5229619 0.1095744 0.3804106 0.2984173
# [2,] 0.9484121 0.5484754 0.6794459 0.6099729 0.3454522
# [3,] 0.2310753 0.8656815 0.4991712 0.8683982 0.8322723
# [4,] 0.9121636 0.1028238 0.4266272 0.3025331 0.3265509

which(DF > 0.9 & DF < 1)
# [1] 2 4

which(DF > 0.9 | DF < 1)
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```